# Local Description of Connection Form on Principal Fiber Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

I'm reading about connections on principal bundles from Kobayashi-Nomizu, and I have a question about the "local picture." I explain the context (taken from chapter II.1 of K-N) and my question below.

Let $\pi: P \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle. Then, by Proposition $1.1$ of K-N, a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-form $\omega$ is a connection form (i.e. its kernel is a $G$-connection on $P$) iff

- $\omega(A^*) = A$, for $A \in \mathfrak{g}$, where $A^*$ is the fundamental vector field associated to $A$;
- $(R_g)^* \omega = \textrm{Ad}(g^{-1}) \omega.$

Now, if $\{(U_\alpha, \psi_\alpha)\}$ a cover of $M$ by local trivializations, where $\psi_\alpha: \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \to U_\alpha \times G$ is of the form $p \mapsto (\pi(p),\varphi_\alpha (p))$, where $\varphi_\alpha(p \cdot g) = \varphi_\alpha(p) \cdot g$. Let $\psi_{\alpha \beta} : U_{\alpha \beta} \to G$, $x \mapsto \varphi_\alpha(\psi_\beta^{-1}(x,e))$, and let $\sigma_\alpha : U_\alpha \to P$, $x \mapsto \psi_\alpha^{-1}(x,e).$

Then, set $\theta_{\alpha \beta} := \psi_{\alpha \beta}^* \theta$, where $\theta$ is the fundamental form of $G$ and $\omega_\alpha := \sigma_\alpha^* \omega$. Proposition 1.4 in K-N says that
\begin{equation}
\omega_\beta = \textrm{Ad}(\psi_{\alpha \beta}^{-1})\omega_\alpha + \theta_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}
on $U_{\alpha \beta}$, and that if $\{\omega_\alpha\}$ is a family that satisfies this, there's a unique $G$-connection form $\omega$ such that $\omega_\alpha = \sigma_\alpha^* \omega$ for all indices $\alpha.$

**I was able to prove that, given $\omega$, the family $\{\omega_\alpha\}$ really satisfies these equations, but not the other way around.**

Here's what I tried: given $\{\omega_\alpha\}$, I set $$\omega|_{\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)} := \pi^* \omega_\alpha + \varphi_\alpha^* \theta.$$ By the condition that this family satisfies, $\omega$ is well-defined, and since $d \pi(A^*) = 0$, it is easy to check that $$\omega(A^*) = A.$$However, I have no idea how to prove $(R_g)^* \omega = \textrm{Ad}(g^{-1}) \omega.$ The given condition only tells me the relationship between $\omega_\alpha$ and $\omega_\beta$, but nothing about them individually.

**EDIT:** here is a computation of the $\varphi_\alpha^* \theta$-part - I obtained that it is $0$, but it is quite possibly wrong.

\begin{align}
((R_g \circ \varphi_\alpha)^* \theta)_p (X) &= \theta_{\varphi_\alpha(p) \cdot g} ((dR_g)_{\varphi_\alpha(p)} \circ (d \varphi_\alpha)_p (X)) \\
&= (dL_{g^{-1} \varphi_\alpha(p)^{-1}})_{\varphi_\alpha(p) g}  \circ (dR_g)_{\varphi_\alpha(p)} \circ (d \varphi_\alpha)_p (X) \\
&= (dL_{g^{-1}})_g \circ (dL_{\varphi_\alpha(p)^{-1}})_{\varphi_\alpha(p)g} \circ (dR_g)_{\varphi_\alpha(p)} \circ (d \varphi_\alpha)_p (X) \\
&= (dC_{g^{-1}})_e \circ (dL_{\varphi_\alpha(p)^{-1}})_{\varphi_\alpha(p)} \circ (d \varphi_\alpha)_p (X) \\
&= (dC_{g^{-1}})_e \circ (dc_e)_p (X) = 0,
\end{align}
where in the last line I used the fact that $L_{\varphi_\alpha(p)^{-1}} \circ \varphi_\alpha = c_e: \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \to G.$

For the $\pi^* \omega_\alpha$-part, I get $$(\pi \circ R_g)^* \omega_\alpha (X) = \omega_\alpha ((d \pi \circ dR_g)(X)) = \omega_\alpha ( d \pi(X)),$$since $\pi \circ R_g = \pi.$ Since I don't know anything about $\omega_\alpha$, I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: This is immediate from the properties of the Maurer-Cartan form. What you have *not* yet checked is well-definedness; when $U_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$ overlap, you will need to use the important property.

Comment: I've checked it, using the said property - I just didn't want to clutter the question even more - this is what I meant by "By the condition that this family satisfies, $\omega$ is well-defined".

Could you elaborate which properties you are referring to?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. It's just the left-invariance of $\theta$, almost tautologically. Write down the definition of $\text{Ad}(g^{-1})$.

Comment: I'm getting that $(R_g)^* (\varphi_\alpha)^* \theta = 0$, by using the definition of $\theta$, the property of $\varphi_\alpha$ that $\varphi_\alpha \circ R_g = R_g \circ \varphi_\alpha$, where $R_g$ on the LHS means the action, and on the RHS the right multiplication in $G$, and the fact that left and right multiplication commute... In the end I get $((R_g \circ \varphi_{\alpha})^*) (X) = (dC_{g^{-1}}) \circ (dL_{\varphi_\alpha(p)^{-1}}) \circ (d \varphi_\alpha)(X) = (dC_{g^{-1}}) \circ (dc_e) (X)$ where $c_e$ is the constant map,so it's $0$. Is this wrong?

Comment: $\theta$ disappeared in this computation.  Where is left-invariance of $\theta$?

Comment: I've included the full computation in an edit of the body, since it was too long for a comment. I believe the left-invariance of $\theta$ is in the definition - it's just $$\theta_g(v) = (dL_{g^{-1}})_g (v).$$

Comment: Since $L_g^*\theta = \theta$ for any $g$, $(\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}})\theta = (L_{g^{-1}}\circ R_g)^*\theta = R_g^*(L_{g^{-1}}^*\theta) = R_g^*\theta
$, as required. I do not have the patience to do through what you've typed.

Comment: I don't see how this implies $R_g^* \omega = \textrm{Ad}(g^{-1}) \omega$. Using the formula that you wrote, I get $$R_g^* \omega = \pi^* \omega_\alpha + \varphi_\alpha^* (\textrm{Ad}(g^{-1}) \theta),$$but I don't know what to do with the first term, or how to continue manipulating the second term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131713/discussion-between-matija-sreckovic-and-ted-shifrin).

Answer (score 1):

You should define $\omega$ on $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ like this:
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_{\varphi_\alpha^{-1}}(\pi^*\omega_\alpha)+\varphi_\alpha^*\theta
$$
Then it is easy to verify that it is a connection form on $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\cong U_\alpha\times G$ and it is well-defined on $P$ by Leibniz's rule (Proposition 1.4).